# Load html file to WebView from local custom folder in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I want to load html file to WebView from local custom folder - `ProjectNameFolder/test/index.html`.

Trying this code, but doesn't work.

```
mWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test/index", ofType: "html")!) as URL))
```

***EDITED***

When I do without folder name, works perfectly.

```
mWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")!) as URL))
```

P.S. I'm new in Swift.

Comment: Why do you think it should be inside a 'test' subfolder?

Comment: @PhillipMills, I have such folder structure. /category/subcategory1/file.html, /category/subcategory2/file.html and so on.

Comment: Are files being copied into that structure as part of the Copy Bundle Resources build phase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution for my problem.

Drag and drop test folder into project folder.

[image]

[image]

Here is code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()     
    mWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test/index", ofType: "html")!)))
}
```